# How to get the URL in Javascript when page is blocked

Tags: javascript, url, bookmarklet, referrer, address-bar

I am trying to build a bookmarklet that will grab the URL from a link that is blocked on my network and run a process on the query string parameters.

I have tried to use window.location.href, but all that is returned is URL of the browsers error page that is displayed, not the URL that generated the error (even though that URL is in the address bar up top.

I get nothing with document.referrer.

This is an example of a URL that this should work on:

https://ue.flipboard.com/usage?data=%7B%22prod_type%22%3A%22notification%22%2C%22event_category%22%3A%22email%22%2C%22event_action%22%3A%22click%22%2C%22event_data%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%2210today.media.sat.20210710.436.2%22%2C%22target_id%22%3A%22104t%2F0%22%2C%22url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fflipboard.com%2F%40businessinsider%2Flabor-shortages-and-calls-for-higher-pay-continue-across-the-us-v632ten2kt4p63a4%3Frefresh%3D1%22%2C%22method%22%3A%22web%22%2C%22redirect_url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fflipboard.com%2F%40businessinsider%2Flabor-shortages-and-calls-for-higher-pay-continue-across-the-us-v632ten2kt4p63a4%3Frefresh%3D1%22%7D%2C%22properties%22%3A%7B%22uid%22%3A%228606374%22%2C%22unique_id%22%3A%228606374%22%2C%22time%22%3A1626124956022%2C%22ab_tests%22%3A%22436_2%22%7D%7D

```js
javascript:(function() {
            let cleanURL = new URL(window.location.href);
            console.log(cleanURL);
            let urlObj = cleanURL.searchParams.get("data");
            urlObj = decodeURIComponent(urlObj);
            let jsonObj = JSON.parse(urlObj);
            window.location.href=jsonObj.event_data.url;
}());
```

[image]

Comment: Please post the link to the url so we can try to debug

Comment: Have you tried it in Chrome?  From what I can tell, it works in Chromium browsers.

Comment: I guess you could parse the html of Safari's error page to get the URL, but it'd only work in Safari

Comment: Added an example URL above. To work out the details I built a script that works when pasting the URL into a text field, but I can't figure out how to access the URL on the original error page to use in the bookmarklet.

Comment: @jmort253 It has not worked in Chrome for me as of yet. I will see if Chromium is better on my linux box.